# Determine if a base64 string or a buffer contains JPEG or PNG without metadata? Possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, ecmascript-6, base64

Is there any way to do this using node, whether natively or with a plugin?

What I'm trying to accomplish is to choose loseless or lossy image compression depending on the input type. Loseless on a large JPEG is a storage catastrophe.

Comment: Where is the base64 data coming from, and why doesn't the source tell you what type the data is?

Comment: Hey Mark, I'm simply not sure yet if it solves my issue as I got pulled in a different direction. I am thinking maybe no, because I'm often dealing with clipboard data, and I'm not sure that it will have the leading bytes that identify the data, but I can't be sure yet. Thank you for your answer though. If it solves my problem, or if I don't get to it soon, as it's the best answer here, I will come back to mark it answered. Thanks again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The first eight bytes of a PNG file always contain the following values - see [PNG Specification](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Rationale.html#R.PNG-file-signature):

```
(decimal)              137  80  78  71  13  10  26  10
(hexadecimal)           89  50  4e  47  0d  0a  1a  0a
(ASCII C notation)    \211   P   N   G  \r  \n \032 \n
```

So, if I take 8 bytes from the start of any PNG file and base64 encode it as follows, I get:

```
head -c8 test.png | base64
iVBORw0KGgo=
```

---

The first 2 bytes of every JPEG file contain `ff` `d8` in hex - see [Wikipedia entry for JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG). So if I take any JPEG file and base64 encode the first two bytes as follows, I get:

```
head -c2 test.jpg | base64
/9g=
```

---

So my suggestion would be to look at the first few (10 for `PNG` and 2 for `JPEG`, always excluding the `=`) characters of your base64-encoded file and see if they match what I am suggesting and then use that as the determinant - be sure to output error messages if your string matches neither in case the test is not sufficiently thorough for some reason!

---

Why 10 characters for PNG? Because the guaranteed signature is 8 bytes, i.e. 64 bits and base64 splits into 6 bits at a time to generate a character, so the first 10 characters are the first 60 bits. The 11th character will vary depending on what follows the signature.

Same logic for JPEG... 2 bytes is 16 bits, which means 2 characters each corresponding to 6 bits are guaranteed. The 3rd character will vary depending on what follows the 2-byte SOI marker.

Answer (score 1):

@MarkSetchell's [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49690539/1183814) is correct in theory.
However, in practice, it doesn't work for JPGs!

It is true that `head -c2 test.jpg | base64` produces `/9g`

However

```
head -c3 test.jpg | base64`
/9j/
```

So, if you want to "Determine if a base64 string or a buffer contains JPEG" you need to test that it starts with `/9j` not `/9g`!

Comment: If you read my answer it explicitly says to test the first 2 characters and that the third will vary…