# How to decode ascii encoded image data to an image file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, base64, decode

## Overview

Handle decoding of base64 encoded image files in a concise and (relatively) comprehensive way.

### Goals

#### Primary Goal

- Use python 3.6 to take an arbitrary base64 string, whether as an 'in-memory' string or external file, and generate an valid image file from it.

#### Secondary Goal

- Use `libmagic` (or some other python library) to determine, as best as is possible, the mime type of an encoded file for directing the correct filetype output.

---

## Preliminary Assumptions

### Encoding is Valid

- A small JPG image was encoded in base64.  I have verified that the encoding was good by viewing the encoded data through web browser using the browser's native decoding device for encoded images. See below.

### This is Doable in Python 3.6

- Seemingly the `base64` package is made for this, unless I'm way off base.

---

## Attempted Solution

### Explaination

I created a python class named `Converter` to handle the task, with the following features

#### Constructor

- `__init__(self, file="none", str_object="none")`

  - Takes 2 string arguments.  Only one is to be specified to replace the default depending on desired usage.
  - `file="none"` - Path to file as a string for file-based decoding.
  - `str_object="none"` - Naked encoded string.

#### Instance Methods

- `convert_ascii_to_byte_stream(self)`

  - No arguments
  - Returns a `base64` object
- `convert_byte_stream_to_jpg(self)`

  - No arguments
  - Opens a new file, attempts to write a byte stream (using `convert_ascii_to_byte_stream`, then closes the file.
  - Returns nothing
- `@staticmethod
  strip_all_whitespace(s)`

  - Takes a single string of arbitrary length.
  - Returns a string with all whitespace, newlines, tabs, and carriage returns removed.

#### Usage

**`__main__.py`**

```
from Converter import *

c = Converter('ascii_image.txt', 'none')  # create Converter instance
# print(c.get_encoding_type()) # attempt to get encoding
c.convert_byte_stream_to_jpg()  # output the decoded data to image file
```

### Observations and Questions

- If I invoke the constructor `Converter('none', 'XyZxYzXyZxYzXyZxYz ...)` then the conversion happens flawlessly.  Obviously there is a problem with the writing to the file.
- I understand the the prefix to the `<img>` source attribute, `data:image/jpg;base64,` must be stripped prior to decoding.  Therefore the test file am using `ascii_image.txt` has been edited to reflect this.
- In the original source there are newlines at the end of each line, and a single blank space at the start of each subsequent line.  Not sure if this makes a difference, especially considering that I am stripping **ALL** whitespace prior to attempting decoding.
- I've tried a bunch of convoluted ways of using `libmagic`, `python-libmagic`, `python-magic-bin`, `file-magic`, and various other extended packages with much confusion and little progress.  Most of them just created a spaghetti stream of error messages about missing dependencies, compiler errors, and other problems.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

---

## Relevant Code and Error Messages

### `Converter` Python Class

```
from io import *
import base64
# import magic


class Converter:

    def __init__(self, file="none", str_object="none"):
        self.file = file
        self.str_object = str_object
        if file == "none" or "":
            self.isFromStringInput = True
            self.asciiString = str_object
        else:
            f = open(file, 'r')
            self.isFromStringInput = False
            # this was the source of the pad error
            #self.asciiString = f.read(file.__len__())
            # changed to ... duh!
            self.asciiString = f.read()
            f.close()

    def convert_byte_stream_to_jpg(self):
        f = open('ascii_image.jpg', 'wb')
        f.write(self.convert_ascii_to_byte_stream())
        f.close()
        return

    def convert_ascii_to_byte_stream(self):
        return base64.b64decode(self.strip_all_whitespace(self.asciiString))

    @staticmethod
    def strip_all_whitespace(s):
        return s.replace('\n', ' ').replace('\r', '').replace('\t', '').replace(' ', '')

    # def get_encoding_type(self):
    #     m = magic.MAGIC_MIME
    #     m.from_bytes(self.convert_ascii_to_byte_stream(), 'little')
    #     return m.file('./' + self.file)
```

### Error Message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/auser/PycharmProjects/btobin/__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
    c.convert_byte_stream_to_jpg()  # output the decoded data to image file
  File "/Users/auser/PycharmProjects/btobin/Converter.py", line 22, in convert_byte_stream_to_jpg
    f.write(self.convert_ascii_to_byte_stream())
  File "/Users/auser/PycharmProjects/btobin/Converter.py", line 27, in convert_ascii_to_byte_stream
    return base64.b64decode(self.strip_all_whitespace(self.asciiString))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding
```

### Correct Encoding Verified

If one places the following `<img>` tag in an html file and opens it with a browser they will see the properly decoded image. 
Here is an example of the [Decoded Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9pRH.jpg)

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/4QAYRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/sABFEdWNr
 eQABAAQAAAAeAAD/4QOPaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS4wLwA8P3hwYWNrZXQgYm
 VnaW49Iu+7vyIgaWQ9Ilc1TTBNcENlaGlIenJlU3pOVGN6a2M5ZCI/PiA8eDp4bXBtZXRhIHht
 bG5zOng9ImFkb2JlOm5zOm1ldGEvIiB4OnhtcHRrPSJBZG9iZSBYTVAgQ29yZSA1LjYtYzAxNC
 A3OS4xNTY3OTcsIDIwMTQvMDgvMjAtMDk6NTM6MDIgICAgICAgICI+IDxyZGY6UkRGIHhtbG5z
 OnJkZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMTk5OS8wMi8yMi1yZGYtc3ludGF4LW5zIyI+IDxyZG
 Y6RGVzY3JpcHRpb24gcmRmOmFib3V0PSIiIHhtbG5zOnhtcE1NPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUu
 Y29tL3hhcC8xLjAvbW0vIiB4bWxuczpzdFJlZj0iaHR0cDovL25zLmFkb2JlLmNvbS94YXAvMS
 4wL3NUeXBlL1Jlc291cmNlUmVmIyIgeG1sbnM6eG1wPSJodHRwOi8vbnMuYWRvYmUuY29tL3hh
 cC8xLjAvIiB4bXBNTTpPcmlnaW5hbERvY3VtZW50SUQ9InhtcC5kaWQ6ZTg0NGJjNjUtYjAzZS
 00ODZiLThlYTctZDFjZTY4OGU5YTc2IiB4bXBNTTpEb2N1bWVudElEPSJ4bXAuZGlkOjM4NTBE
 Njg5Mzg2MzExRTZCOEZERTBFNjU0NTg5RUZDIiB4bXBNTTpJbnN0YW5jZUlEPSJ4bXAuaWlkOj
 M4NTBENjg4Mzg2MzExRTZCOEZERTBFNjU0NTg5RUZDIiB4bXA6Q3JlYXRvclRvb2w9IkFkb2Jl
 IFBob3Rvc2hvcCBDQyAyMDE0IChNYWNpbnRvc2gpIj4gPHhtcE1NOkRlcml2ZWRGcm9tIHN0Um
 VmOmluc3RhbmNlSUQ9InhtcC5paWQ6MjU4YjBiOTEtNGJhMC00NjI0LTg5NTUtYjU2ODg0OWIw
 OWFhIiBzdFJlZjpkb2N1bWVudElEPSJhZG9iZTpkb2NpZDpwaG90b3Nob3A6ZTllYjAwMGQtOD
 A0My0xMTc5LThhODktZjZmMjZkYTVhZGU1Ii8+IDwvcmRmOkRlc2NyaXB0aW9uPiA8L3JkZjpS
 REY+IDwveDp4bXBtZXRhPiA8P3hwYWNrZXQgZW5kPSJyIj8+/+4ADkFkb2JlAGTAAAAAAf/bAI
 QAEAsLCwwLEAwMEBcPDQ8XGxQQEBQbHxcXFxcXHx4XGhoaGhceHiMlJyUjHi8vMzMvL0BAQEBA
 QEBAQEBAQEBAQAERDw8RExEVEhIVFBEUERQaFBYWFBomGhocGhomMCMeHh4eIzArLicnJy4rNT
 UwMDU1QEA/QEBAQEBAQEBAQEBA/8AAEQgASwBLAwEiAAIRAQMRAf/EAH0AAAICAwEAAAAAAAAA
 AAAAAAAGBAUCAwcBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAABAgQDBQUDCgMJAAAAAAABAgMAEQQFIR
 IGMUFRcRNhgZEiMqFCFLHRUmJygpIjM0PBgxWywrMkRIQ1RWURAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/
 2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AOgQQRUX6/N2lpLbaevXP4U7AxJJwzKljKfjAT6yvo6BrrVjyWW9xUcSeA
 G090UC9YOVSy3Z7e9WEfuEFKfYD7ZQW/TDtY6LjqFZqalWKacn8tscDL5Bhzhib+HaAZayNhOC
 W0yTLkkQC8K7WzgzIoGGx9FShP8AxI8N81TSGdZaQ42PUpgkmX3SuGeCAo7dq21VywytRpKjZ0
 3vLjwCtkXcV9zsdtuqCKpodSXleT5XB97fyMULVXctK1CKW4KNVaHDlZqJEqb7N/4fw8IBvgjF
 txDqEuNqC0LAUlQMwQcQRGUBoratqhpHat4ybZSVHiZbAOZwhf0xQO1ry9RXEZqmpJ+GSdjbey
 Y+QdnOMtYrXUfAWhsyNa+M/wBhJH8TPuhiabQ02hpsZUNpCUpG4JEgIBK1NqSrcqn7bSK6NO0e
 m64kkOLUPUMw2J3QsyE5+9x3+MT74ytm81qFggl5SxPelfnB9sQYBm0je6tNai21Dinad4ENFZ
 mptaRmkFHGRAh3jmWnwo3yhy7er7AlU4btY19RR2xCaZZaXUOBtTicFBMioyO6coCfUX6z0rpZ
 frGkOJwUnNMg9spyjYsW+8US2gpFTTOjKooIPgRsIjl0vnMWul6tylvdOlskIqVdJ1G5QIJST2
 gwF/pyoftdxe05WKzBE3KJw+8g+aQ5jHnmhphX1k2aZVDemsHaR0JUeKD5gPYR3ww/GMfS/a63
 8vjAUNzAc1na0K2IZWsc/wAz5oZYWNQn4XUVnrlGTalFhR4ZjL+/DPAc21Ol1N+qw6oqJKSgnc
 gpGUDsGMVcPOtLaupoUVrcs1FmU4DtLapZpcpThGgJVsYeqLlSssEpdU6khSZzSEnMpWHACHHW
 4b/o6SoEq6yOmRsBxnm7JTiLoWhKWqi4qIIdPRQkbQGzNRPMmL+725u5W92lWJlQzN4yk4nFB8
 YDl8SrW8Ke6Ub5SV5HkeRO05jlw8YjLQ40tTTySh1BKXEHalQ2iGDRtsFXXqrHkFTNJItqnIdb
 dzypx8IBh1ehK9P1U/dyKHMLTFV8S5ln/wCFm780on63f6dkLKT56hxCEp4yOc/2Y3f0deyX/W
 /B/egM9U21VxtDiWhOoYPWZltJRtA5icRKPWFtFqYqKtw/FFOVxhAKllacCZcDtxhjhD1VYFUL
 y7hSpnROnM6kfsrJxP2FHwMBEvmoam8KSjJ0KZskpbCiVKmJfmEYHlFTBBAT7Pd37RVGoaSHUr
 TkcaUSAUznNMth7oZH9Zs1FIU0SQxVqEv8yciEz3pWkKBPCcoTIIDdVNVba+pVhZW6Zl5UlBwn
 fnTNJMTLJe37PUFYSXadYk4xmyieHnG7MJSiFT1L1NMNK/LV+oyoZmljgtBwPywNtOVVSGaVol
 x5UmmUkmXZM7hxMAziqGqL/SBpCk0FCnrOBYxzz2HmQAO+HGKyw2Zu0UQZmF1Dhz1Dg95fAfVT
 sEWcARipKVpKFgKSoSUk4gg7jGUEAoXfRU1KftKgmeJpVmSf5at3Iwr1VHWUaslWw4weK0nL3K
 9Ptjq8a3v0lenZ7/p74DkudJ2KHjAFBRkk5lbgMT4CHio/UP8Aw239z1RY2r1f6H/Z7YBMt2mb
 vXkENGmZO154FOH1Ueow62ew0VobPRBcfWJOVC/WrsH0R2CLOCAIIIID/9k=" />
```

Comment: This is related... https://stackoverflow.com/a/49690539/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks for that.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I invoked the constructor using the "naked string" method the encoded data as a single line string, and viola, ... that worked.  Must be missing something in reading from the file.

Comment: Ahh.  Ok, so I made an error in assuming that file.read() was only going to read line by line, and so I added the `file.__len__()` as an argument.  Removing that fixed the file pad error.