# Get image type from binary data image & convert it to actual image in PHP

Tags: php, image, base64, binary-data, binary-image

frankly speaking, I'm not sure if this is duplication of another question since the context should be different.

I currently working with some API that returns status & contents(binary data image) which I will base64 encode at first. The question is how to initially get the image type on it's binary data form, & after that convert it to actual image with its type extension. In this scenario, I'm using PHP since it involves with backend task.
Thanks.

updates:
for this case, I get the image in binary form from external site api. I use file_get_contents but it returns empty or null. When i use base64_encode then it will shows up the image as an encoded data. the issue is I need to convert it as normal image. I try getimagesize as encoded & decoded & try to print the output & it returns empty. 
is there any steps I am still missing?

Comment: Do you need [getimagesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)?

Comment: I guess no since what I need is its original image type & how to convert it back to normal image.

Comment: I think this helps... https://stackoverflow.com/a/49690539/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks buddy. I go to it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your 2 questions:

> how to convert it back to normal image.

If the image is simply encode with base64, then of course decode it with [base64_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) got the original image data.

```
$original_image = base64_decode($encoded_base64_string);
```

> I guess no since what I need is its original image type

Don't be confused by it's name, [getimagesize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) also tells you the image type and the mime type.

Comment: thanks for suggestion. let me try first & get back to you once get the results.
Sorry for my confusion. =)

Comment: thanks buddy. Just use the base64_decode after all the try and error. I can assume the issues is solved as per my situations.