# Image byte array not displaying in <img> tag

Tags: html, image, asp.net-core, blazor

My Blazor app is receiving a periodic byte array containing image data.  It is put into a .razor class property called `ImageData`.

This view / disaply markup looks like this:

```
<img src="@($"data:image/png;base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(ImageData)}")">
```

The data is in RGB24 format - RGBA pixel format.

However, the rendered web view always shows this classic "icon missing" image:
[image]

Comment: can you post final result from browser's developer tools?

Comment: Show us the code especially where the ImageData is updated

Comment: make sure the base64 string is valid for png format,a related issue here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49664561/determine-if-a-base64-string-or-a-buffer-contains-jpeg-or-png-without-metadata

Comment: Since you indicated `image/png`, the data encoded in the base64 needs to be that same it would be in a PNG file.

Comment: inspect the img element via DevTools and see what its `src` is set to. also refresh page while devtools is open so you can see if any errors are present in the console.

Comment: is `ImageData` a byte array? because it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little snippet that I use that can convert local path or images on a URL to base64. This should be sufficient to guide you in identifying your issue.

PS: More code from you would've been helpful.

```
try
{
    byte[] imageData;

    if (ImagePathIsUrl)
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(ImagePath);

        imageData = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        imageData = await File.ReadAllBytesAsync(ImagePath);
    }

    new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().TryGetContentType(ImagePath, out string? contentType); //This will ensure the correct mimetype. Haven't seen this fail.

    ImageDataUri = $"data:{contentType};base64,{Convert.ToBase64String(imageData)}";
}
catch
{
    ImageDataUri = Helpers.Constants.NotFoundImage; //Some base64 string that returns an image displaying an error
}
```